# Problem with curve_fit using a trig function of numerical integration

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, trigonometry, calculus

Attempting to fit a model to observational data. The code uses data in the range of 0.5 to 1.0 for the independent variable with scipy curve_fit and numerical integration. The function to be integrated also includes an unknown parameter, then subjecting the integrand to evaluation using the trig function sinh(integrand).

After applying curve_fit I get an error message of "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type function which has no callable sinh method". Have I hit a dead end with Python 3? Hope not.

This evaluation code is

```
#O_m, Hu are unknown parameters to be estimated with model, data

def integr(x,O_m):
    return intg.quad(lambda x: 1/x(np.sqrt((O_m/x) + (1-O_m))) , x, 1, args=(0.02))[0]

O_m = 0.02 #Guess for value of O_m, which shall lie between 0.01 and 1.0

def funcX(x,O_m):
    result = np.asarray([integr(xx,O_m) for xx in x]) * np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))
    return result

litsped=299793 #the constant speed of light in a vacuum (m/s)

def funcY(x,Hu,O_m):
    return (litsped/(x * Hu * np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))))*np.sinh(funcX)

init_guess = [65,0.02]
bnds=([50,0.001],[80,1.0])

params, pcov = curve_fit(funcY, xdata, ydata, p0 = init_guess, bounds = bnds, sigma = error, absolute_sigma = True)

ans_Hu, ans_O_m = params
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
```

---

Complete code below - as far as I have gotten with this curve_fit.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import integrate as intg

with open("Riess_1998_D_L.csv",'r') as i:  #SNe Ia data file
    rawdata = list(csv.reader(i,delimiter=",")) #make a data list

exmdata = np.array(rawdata[1:],dtype=float) #convert to data array
xdata = exmdata[:,1]
ydata = exmdata[:,2]
error = exmdata[:,3]

#plot of imported data
plt.title("Observed SNe Ia Data")
plt.figure(1,dpi=120)
plt.xlabel("Expansion factor")
plt.ylabel("Distance (Mpc)")
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,label = "Observed SNe Ia data")
plt.xlim(0.5,1)
plt.ylim(0.0,9000)
plt.xscale("linear")
plt.yscale("linear")
plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr=error, fmt='.k', capsize = 4)

# O_m and Hu are the unknown parameters which shall be estimated using the model and observational data
def integr(x,O_m):
    return intg.quad(lambda x: 1/x(np.sqrt((O_m/x) + (1-O_m))) , x, 1, args=(0.02))[0]
O_m = 0.02 # Guess for value of O_m, which are between 0.01 and 1.0
def funcX(x,O_m):
    result = np.asarray([integr(xx,O_m) for xx in x])* np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))
    return result

litsped=299793 #the constant speed of light in a vacuum (m/s)
def funcY(x,Hu,O_m):
return (litsped/(x*Hu*np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))))*np.sinh(funcX)

init_guess = [65,0.02]
bnds=([50,0.001],[80,1.0])

params, pcov = curve_fit(funcY, xdata, ydata, p0 = init_guess, bounds = bnds, sigma = error, absolute_sigma = True)
ans_b, ans_c = params
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

TotalInt = intg.trapz(ydata,xdata) #Compute numerical integral to check data import

print("The total area is: ", TotalInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would be useful, e.g. what is your xdata/ydata? Could you rewrite your code as a minimal reproducable example?

P.S. you can format things on stackoverflow as code by writing ``` before and after the code for better readability ;)

Comment: My initial guess is this: You pass the FUNCTION funcX ITSELF to sinh. What you probably should do, is to pass something like np.sinh(funcX(x,O_m)). But for more details, I would prefer to have a complete code from you first ;) thx

Comment: Have entered the "complete" code. Note: Have presented a few data pairs from independent variable of 1 to 0.5076. I wonder if the order might be better from 0.5076 to 1 ? (Order doesn't make a difference with much older FORTRAN programs I have previously used but I have no experience with python curve_fit.)

Comment: okay sorry to bother you again, but I cant reproduce the example as long as I dont have the "Riess_1998_D_L.csv" file. could you instead maybe set rawdata to some array of some sort? The idea of a minimal reproducible example is for me to try it myself on a python notebook etc, not to just understand your code from looking at it.
Apart from that, again you put sinh(funcX) and not its arguments and you didnt indent the "return" correctly in funcY. And I think one line is not formated correctly between the 2 code blocks. But thx for the code so far. Would be great if you could add those details

Comment: Okay, yes your initial error is because you put the function itself in the sinh. But now I have even more questions: What exactly does your funcX do? Shouldnt x be just a float number? You somehow pretend to integrate it, as if x was an array of functions.

Comment: Also, you should not pass 0.02 as an argument in intgr, since your lambda x: function only takes one argument and no parameters. Furthermore you forgot a "*" sign in that function between 1/x and (np.sqrt... I think that none of your functions work independently.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the fitting procedure. It was a bit hard for me to understand the code. IF I understood correctly, I recommend sth like this:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import integrate as intg

exmdata = np.array(np.random.random((10,4)),dtype=float) #convert to data array
xdata = exmdata[:,1]
ydata = exmdata[:,2]
error = exmdata[:,3]

#plot of imported data
plt.title("Observed SNe Ia Data")
plt.figure(1,dpi=120)
plt.xlabel("Expansion factor")
plt.ylabel("Distance (Mpc)")
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,label = "Observed SNe Ia data")
plt.xlim(0.5,1)
plt.ylim(0.0,9000)
plt.xscale("linear")
plt.yscale("linear")
plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr=error, fmt='.k', capsize = 4)

# O_m and Hu are the unknown parameters which shall be estimated using the model and observational data
def integr(x,O_m):
    return 5*x+3*O_m#Some analytical form

O_m = 0.02 # Guess for value of O_m, which are between 0.01 and 1.0

def funcX(x,O_m):
    result = integr(x,O_m)* np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))
    return result

litsped=299793 #the constant speed of light in a vacuum (m/s)

def funcY(x,Hu,O_m):
    return (litsped/(x*Hu*np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))))*np.sinh(funcX(x,O_m))

init_guess = np.array([65,0.02])
bnds=([50,0.001],[80,1.0])


params, pcov = curve_fit(funcY, xdata, ydata, p0 = init_guess, bounds = bnds, sigma = error, absolute_sigma = True)
```

Where you still need to put in an analytical form of the integral in intgr and replace my random arrays with your CSV file data. The error you referred to earlier was indeed due to you passing the whole function instead of the function evaluated at some point. Please first try to implement these steps and make sure that you can call your three functions independently without errors. It is quite hard to search for bugs, if you tackle the whole program immediately. Try to make the individual parts work first ;). If you still need help after you have implemented these changes, say for the actual fitting procedure, just ask me again ;).